# Full screen is flickering: LWJGL

Tags: lwjgl

I've seen questions about the LWJGL window flickering during rendering, but I'm talking about the full screen flickering here, not just the window. The flickers are ~1.5 seconds long of the normal computer screen, then ~1.5 seconds of full black.

I'm not trying to run the app in full screen.

I'm using the code from [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i8vhMiai7QE&index=2&list=PLzUGFf4GhXBLkgMfFfxh0LlEtDMRsKECS), that I rewrote in Kotlin:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>){
    SharedLibraryLoader.load()

    thread {
        Main.run()
    }
}

object Main: Runnable {

    val window: Long

    init {
        if (glfwInit() != GL_TRUE)
            throw RuntimeException("Couldn't initialize GLFW...")

        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_TRUE)

        window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Test", NULL, NULL)
        if (window == NULL)
            throw RuntimeException("Couldn't create the window...")

        val videoMode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor())
        glfwSetWindowPos(window, 100, 100)
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window)
        glfwShowWindow(window)
    }

    fun update() {
        glfwPollEvents()
    }

    fun render() {
        glfwSwapBuffers(window)
    }

    override fun run() {
        while (glfwWindowShouldClose(window) != GL_TRUE){
            update()
            render()
        }
    }

}
```

with the Gradle dependencies:

```
val lwjglVersion = "3.0.0a"
compile("org.lwjgl:lwjgl:${lwjglVersion}")
compile("org.lwjgl:lwjgl-platform:${lwjglVersion}:natives-windows")
compile("org.lwjgl:lwjgl-platform:${lwjglVersion}:natives-linux")
compile("org.lwjgl:lwjgl-platform:${lwjglVersion}:natives-osx")
```

I'm on a Debian 9 machine (Linux). Is this a graphics card problem? Or is the code just wrong?

Comment: @httpdigest I just upgraded to 3.2.1, and it broke all my calls to glfw methods, was their name changed? Sorry this is probably obvious, but I just started LWJGL

Comment: Also, `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)` gives me `java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is no OpenGL context current in the current thread.` (in 3.0.0a)

Comment: I'm using the dependency https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.lwjgl/lwjgl/3.2.1 and it doesn't seem like I can call any method.

Comment: @httpdigest thanks a lot, after doing everything you've said it now works correctly!